# Windows Phone Mango : Has anyone seen Bing Search Extras in action?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

The new feature Bing search extras, provides deep integration with your applications so that user's search could be re-directed to your application. Microsoft has published detailed how-tos:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286420(v=VS.92).aspx

And you would watch video here to witness the demostration:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone17-Search-Extras

However, when I used the sample applications from Microsoft and do as instructed, I don't see it in actions at all. I'm aware that the new feature is available in certain regions. But I have changed my regional informaiton to English(United States) and had no Cards showing up.

So, my question is: is the feature real? Have you used it at all?

Thanks

Simo

Comment: use the emulator not the device, and connect your pc to a US vpn, and see if that works.